# Google Static Maps API 403 Error With IP Restriction

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I've ran into a strange problem with Google's static maps API.

For some reason, when there is an IP restriction (I.E the server's IP address set where it says Google Static Maps API 403 Error With IP Restriction), the API notw returns a 403 error.

Stupidly, if I try and access the URL of my request using the key, from other IP addresses, it works, but not from the only one it should do. Also, if I remove the key, it returns the image.

See http://www.burnsidemotorcompany.com. The image towards the bottom of the page that isn't showing, is where the problem lies.

[image]

Something else to note, is that I have tried doing CURL requests to the URL via PHP, and they are successful. I really don't understand why it's suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Any information in the Google API console for that key?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. No, the console simply shows the number of errors. Unless I am completely mistaking this IP restriction feature, it is working in the exact opposite way that it should. It will allow any IP address to make calls using this API key, except for the 1 IP address I have specified!

Comment: The way I usually do it is `*.domain.com/*` and then another record for `domain.com/*` perhaps that helps?  Maybe the stars at the end are needed?